# How do i make concurrent request to an APi endpoint in Python? Receiving error: expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, api, concurrency, python-requests

I have a python script that is sending concurrent requests to an API endpoint. When using the rick and morty API endpoint it works fine. But when I try to send it to my local Node server, it gives me the following error.

```
Looks like something went wrong: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Does anyone know why? Code is below

```
import requests
import concurrent
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import time
characters = range(1, 10)
base_url = 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character'
test_url = 'http://localhost:8080'
threads = 20

def get_character_info(character):
    headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer MYREALLYLONGTOKENIGOT"}
    r = requests.get(f'{test_url}/{character}')
    return r.json()

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=threads) as executor:
    start_time = time.time()
    future_to_url = {executor.submit(get_character_info, char) for char in characters}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        try:
            data = future.result()
            print(data)
        except Exception as e:
            print('Looks like something went wrong:', e)
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
    # 0.9544878005981445
```

Comment: Try adding the line `r.raise_for_status()` after `r = requests.get(...)`, the request may not have been succesful and this will raise an appropriate exception

Comment: hmm looks like it is giving me the same error even with that line